# Error while build sencha touch 2.3 package

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch

I wanna run a native android package in emulator, I use sencha cmd 4.x and sencha touch 2.3.0, but after I used sencha app build -run native i got this error

```
    [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Development\sencha\NotesApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:414: The following error occurred
while executing this line:
D:\Development\sencha\NotesApp\.sencha\app\cordova-impl.xml:137: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
jar:file:/D:/Development/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:5
94: shellscript returned: -1073741571
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:55
1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:127)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironme
nt.java:394)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands
.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:130)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Development\sencha\NotesApp\.sencha\app\cordova-impl.xml:137: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
jar:file:/D:/Development/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:5
94: shellscript returned: -1073741571
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:55
1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:108)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.j
ava:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:127)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironme
nt.java:394)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands
.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:130)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/D:/Development/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:5
94: shellscript returned: -1073741571
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:55
1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.j
ava:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:108)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.j
ava:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:127)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironme
nt.java:394)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands
.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:130)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
   Caused by: shellscript returned: -1073741571
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.platform.ShellScriptTask.execute(ShellScriptTask.java:132)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.j
ava:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:108)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.j
ava:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:127)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironme
nt.java:394)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands
.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:130)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
```

I installed all packages that I need, my soft and installed apps are:
Windows 7 Pro x64
Java 1.7
Sencha CMD 4
Sencha touch 2.3.0
Ruby 1.9.3
Compass, Sass
Ant
and all PATHes are correct. it's about 3 hours I'm trying find somethin in web, but there is no any answer for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had some error in Windows7 64bit, but after 2 days I compile my .APK

So, it is my steps:

1. Installed Java 1.7 **32bit** !!! It was SURPRISE for me :)
2. Download Android ADT **32bit**. Run Android SDK Manager and install API Level 18
3. Start Windows Cmd as Administrator

At last in Cmd4:

1. cd sencha-touch2.3.0
2. sencha generate app test ../test
3. cd ../
4. cd test
5. sencha phonegap init com.test.test test
6. modify file in the project folder "phonegap.local.properties". this line

   phonegap.platform=android
7. finally in the Cmd4 run:  sencha app build native

Answer (score 0):

I was faced by a similar problem and it was quiet upsetting... here is the work around (tried on both 32 & 64bit versions of Java SDK)
1) Do your java installation and set the path to your system environment.
2) Download apache anti and extract it your desirable location. Copy the link to its bin folder and paste it in your class path variables. 
Open your command prompt and type ant.
Let me know if your are still stack